# Excel dynamic column value based on other columns

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet where the A column is a list of email address and columns C-P represent VLOOKUP formulas to return a phone number. Each column represents a different source.
C-P columns will only contain one value and the rest will be #N/A. How do I fill the B column with the valid value from the C-P columns, assuming there is one?

I tried to do a formula using nested IFNAs but it seems to be the case that Excel only allows up to 8 nested if statements, and there are more than 8 columns in my spreadsheet so that is not a valid solution for my problem.

I believe this should be possible using formulas alone so I was hoping to find a solution that accomplishes that. Does anyone have any ideas on how I may be able to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Like the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff), the newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can provide cyclic processing with some of its sub-functions but also discard errors.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:P2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(A:O)/SIGN(LEN(C2:P2)), 1)), "")
```

I've added an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) wrappe to avoid another `#N/A` in case *'assuming there is one'* is not correct.